# Wireless firmware installation w/no connection

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a Compaq Presario V5000 (V5102NR specific) and can't get the wireless network to work (54g 802.11b/g WLAN with 125HSM BCM4318).

I've tried to install by copying b43-fwcutter-015 & B43 1.5 into `/lib/firmware/` file to not avail.

I used this command to input them:

```
sudo cp -r ~/wireless/* /lib/firmware/
```

My wireless didn't work after restart and now I can't delete these files becuase I don't have **owner** permission even though I changed my group to **root**.

The current settings say:

```
Kernel river in use: b43-pci-bridge
kernel modules: ssb
```

Network connection still says firmware missing. I do not have a wired connection although I do have another laptop thats connected to a hotspot.

I've been trying all day. Help!!!!

**Note:** My first time using Ubuntu or any Linux based OS.

Comment: check out the howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access

Answer (score 1):

I guess you picked up from somewhere that you need to use the b43-fwcutter - that is most probably correct.  However, you look like you've incorrectly used this package.

The usual way to-do this is to connect your laptop via a wired connection to the internet.

Then launch the *Additional Drivers* window.  From there you will be able to activate you Broadcom driver.

From the command-line, this is similar - you just install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Given that you said that you dont have a wired connection then you will need to use the [community instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access) to do the following:

1. Grab the b43-fwcutter package off the live USB/Live CD and install it
2. Using another computer that is connected to the internet, download the firmware
3. Then using some terminal commands, extract the firmware and install it
4. Activate the new b43 driver

Answer (score 0):

You can download packages from the packages.ubuntu.com web page anytime.

To find whick package you need, start the Additional drivers or `jockey-gtk`, and activate the driver. If I am correct, it will produce an error, which is stored into a log (it will be in the error message). Read the log, and the package you will need will be there. Grab it with the other laptop. You can install it with `sudo dpkg -i` /path/to/package. Reboot, and it will work.